# Can not read property of undefined (when it is defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to scroll to top of the element when it is opened (this is using bootstrap 3 accordion structure), but I get an error saying 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined' where undefined is `heading` I guess? I'm not sure why tis happens as everything else I perform on the `heading` i.e. `removeClass()` works.

```
$('.checkout .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    var heading =
        $('.checkout')
        .find('a[aria-controls="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');

    heading.removeClass('complete')
        .css('cursor', 'default');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: heading.offset().top - 100
    }, 'slow');
});
```

EDIT: it seems that heading returns empty object when `$(html, body).ani ...` is added in, however if I remove that part it returns what is expected.

Comment: looks like `heading` is returning an empty jQuery object...

Comment: @ArunPJohny i don't thinks so `everything else I perform on the heading i.e. removeClass() works`

Comment: Can you try `position()` instead of `offset()`, not sure if it'll help

Comment: for sure `heading` is an empty jQuery object (length 0), there is no other option

Comment: Is it possible that `heading` has a `display:none` (or is nested inside such element...) or anything else that makes it invisible?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi But how come it works fine and console prints out correct element associated to heading when I remove scroll to top bit.

Comment: please debug your code and check it, we can easily find it out.

Comment: You didn't respond, but you should know that if the element inside the jQuery instance in `heading` isn't "visible", you'll get that behavior -> `offset()` will return undefined.

Comment: @Amit it has display:none elements inside it though

Comment: @IIja have you tried my code

Comment: place a          console.log(heading);       call after the heading variable to see if the object is empty.  Which it probably is not since you are stating that the heading removeClass works.  So after you have confirmed that place another   console.log(heading); call  after the heading.removeClass call.  There is either a problem with scope or something is setting it to undefined. You just have to print to the console in different spots to see where the problem develops exactly.

Comment: methods like removeClass will work on an empty jQuery object... but `offset` will return `undefined` if there is no element found... which can explain your problem

Comment: the fact that `removeClass` doesn't throw (or fail in general) is that even if `heading` is an empty jQuery object, there's no problem with that. `offset()` on the other hand, will return undefined

Comment: Hehe.. @ArunPJohny you were 28 secs faster :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking using jQuery's `length` property to see whether such an element exists

```
if (heading.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: heading.offset().top - 100
    }, 'slow');
}
```

Comment: Can you explain `everything else I perform on the heading i.e. removeClass() works`

Comment: Just tried it out, returns 1 if I remove scrolling up bit, but 0 if it is added in.

Comment: @Tushar everything else id `removeClass` which will work correctly in an empty jQuery object.... but `offset()` will return undefined

Comment: Inside that `on` function before you do anything else just console `heading` variable and see what you actually get

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code **heading** is not work inside animate method so you have to replace it as given below

```
$('.checkout .collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
var heading =
    $('.checkout')
    .find('a[aria-controls="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]');

heading.removeClass('complete')
    .css('cursor', 'default');

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.checkout').find('a[aria-controls="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').offset().top - 100
}, 'slow');
```

});

Hope this will help you ..!!!